# mysql join phone calls join with client pissible phones

Tags: mysql

I got a table named phonecalls with 
call_id (int, AA) , number  varchar(50), calldate   varchar(50)
and one named Clients
with
id (int, AA), clientname, phone1, phone2, phone3

There might be duplicate client names and phones in Clients table.

How can i display all the phonecalls records and if the number matches part of any of the 3 phone number fields?

Eaxmple data:

### phonecalls

```
1, 12345, 1/1/2016
2, 5555, 2/2/2016
3, 55551. 3/1/2016
4, 888, 8/1/2016
```

### Clients

```
1, John Doe, 0010 123456, 001033333, null
2, Joan Doe, null, 55557, null 
3, Sam Doe, null, 55558, 55551
4, Joan Doe, null, 5555, 234234
5. Alan Doe, 2222, 66666, 8888
```

how can i get as results this:

```
1, 12345, 1/1/2016, 1, John Doe, 0010 123456, 001033333, null
2, 5555, 2/2/2016, 2, Joan Doe, null, 55557, null (only the first one found matching one of their phones) 
3, 55551. 3/1/2016, null, nulll, null, null  (not found)
4, 888, 8/1/2016, 5. Alan Doe, 2222, 66666, 8888
```

thanks

Comment: how did 888 match to 8888?

Comment: nvm, i see you are matching by prefix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `left join` to preserve "not found" cases
- `a.number = left(b.phone1,length(a.number))` to join on prefix
- `or` to match on phone1,2,3
- `group by a.call_id` to keep only 1 row per call

query:

```
select a.*, b.*
from phonecalls a
left join clients b on instr(b.phone1, a.number) 
                    or instr(b.phone2, a.number)
                    or instr(b.phone3, a.number) 
group by a.call_id;
```

Comment: Thank you. This is only working when a.number equal b.phoneX
It does nto returning the client phone numbers that contains a part of the phonecall number.
For example if i have a.number = 888 and a client a.phone = 28883 it's returning NULL fields.
Do you have any recomendations about this?
I was trying something like the following but it doesnt work either.

SELECT c.*, p.* 
FROM phonecalls as p 
LEFT JOIN clients as c ON ( c.phone1 LIKE CONCAT('%', p.number, '%') OR c.phone2 LIKE CONCAT('%', p.number, '%') OR c.phone3 LIKE CONCAT('%', p.number, '%')) 
ORDER BY p.`call_id`

any ideas?
thanks.

Comment: @WilliamBird, `instr` should do the job. see updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I was trying to solve it with LIKE instead of INSTR.